# can not scan from Canon MF260 to computer

Tags: printing, scanner, canon

**Some Information**

Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.4.LTS
Printer make and model: Canon MF260

`lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7`

```
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
      bInterfaceClass         7 Printer
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Printer
      bInterfaceProtocol      4 
      iInterface              0 
--
      bInterfaceClass         7 Printer
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Printer
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Bidirectional
      iInterface              0 
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
Couldn't open device, some information will be missing
--
      bInterfaceClass         7 Printer
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Printer
      bInterfaceProtocol      4 
      iInterface              0 
--
      bInterfaceClass         7 Printer
      bInterfaceSubClass      1 Printer
      bInterfaceProtocol      2 Bidirectional
      iInterface              0
```

**Context**
I can print a document from my computer to the printer through a cable connected between my computer and the printer.

However, I can not find a way to scan any documents. I do not see a GUI on my computer. I do not see anyway to scan from the settings/printer tab on Ubuntu. When I press the scan button on the printer, I see three choices appear on the printer touch screen:

- computer
- e-mail
- file

When I press computer on the printer touch screen, it states, "Connect the computer."  The computer is already connected.

How can I resolve this issue?

**Attempt 1**

In terminal, I type *sudo sane-find-scanner*. the result is

```
  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x06cb, product=0x00bd) at libusb:001:004
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04a9 [Language Error], product=0x27f4 [Language Error]) at libusb:001:009
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.
```

**Attempt 2**

When I type *scanimage -L*

I get back

> device `pixma:MF260_Canon8d878b' is a CANON Canon i-SENSYS MF260 Series multi-function peripheral device` pixma:04A927F4_1ACB118D878B' is a CANON Canon i-SENSYS MF260 Series multi-function peripheral

**Attempt 3**

I went to https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/black-and-white-laser/canon-imageclass-mf269dw

I downloaded the recommended driver that is called

> UFR II/UFRII LT Printer Driver for Linux V5.50

There was a very many files in several folders. I found one called *cnrdrvcups-ufr2-us_5.50-1.00_amd64.db* I installed this. Then I was able to get a program called **Canon UFR I...* to appear. But this program has no options about scanning, and it is not a GUI about scanning.

**Attempt 4**

I try to download scangear.

I did a google search. Then I was picked an option from google and went to an https://my.canon/en/support/0100949101

There, I found

> ScanGear MP Ver. 3.60 for Linux (debian Packagearchive)

Again, as I did in Attempt 3, I downloaded the zipped drivers and then extracted the files from the zip.

Once again, I am stuck. I do not know what to do with the files that I have. How do I load the drivers? Is this done through the terminal?

When I go through my file system, I found files called:

- *scangearmp2_3.60-1_amd64.deb*
- *scangearmp2_3.60-1_i386.deb*

Are these the drivers?

**Attempt 5**

looked for scan software from ubuntu respository. Found something called *scanlite* . I loaded it. Upon attemtpign to launch it said it cannot find any scanners and that I should go to SANE website.

**Attempt 6**

Trying another program from the ubunto software repository. It is called IPPUSB. Like another review of this software, the result is that, "Supposedly installs; on launch the box flashes and disappears. Nada. I wish something would work."

**Attempt 7. Simple.printer (i.e., Document Scanner)**

This program was able to generate spinning gears in the printer. However, the resulting image was useless.  See example below.

** Attempt 8**

Michael Gruz

[image]

**Attempt 9**

Xsane appears to be working, but only somewhat.

I have been playing with XSane but want to now do a more thorough study of the matter at hand. To begin with, when I open XSane, I get a prompt. The prompt changes from time to time when I open it. I have attached an image below. In this image there are two such propts. The first is a prompt that I get when the USB is unplugged. Maybe these two options in the prompt come from the WIFI connection between my router and the printer. The second prompt has more options. I do not know which of these options is the right one to choose

[image]

Comment: Start by installing Sane (basic) or XSane (full). If neither detects the MFP then you have to install drivers and additional software from Canon, namely Scanjet.

Comment: How do I download scanjet from canon? On canon webpage or from ubuntu software program?

Comment: Yes, from the Canon website like you'd do with any other drivers for any other OS. But, again, first install the scanning software because it may work as is.

Comment: Ok. As I show above, I found a driver that is recommendded by Canon. The driver is not called Scanjet. The driver is called UFR II/UFRII LT Printer Driver for Linux V5.50 What do I do with the driver? I have downloaded it, but do not know what to do with the file.

Comment: Indeed the printer's driver is the only one shown for your model. This suggests it also works with simple.scan or XSane like mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no idea what you mean by your last comment. What do I do with the driver? Is there a command to type into the terminal? If so, then what might it be?

Comment: My last comment was a complement to the now deleted one from the other user. In a nutshell, you may not need anything else from Canon. But you need scanning software and that can be either one I mentioned before and those are available at the Ubuntu repositories. So, just search them with Ubuntu Software. Now, back to the beginning, if those don't detect the scanner then - and only then - we need to start troubleshooting some other way.

Comment: I tried scanlite, which I found in Ubuntu software. Upon launch it says, *Sorry no devices found* ... go to SANE website...

Comment: Install `scangearmp2_3.60-1_amd64.deb`and try again

Comment: I go to the file called *scangearmp2_3.60-1_amd64.deb*. Then I right click and I see *Reinstall package*. I press *Reinstall package*. The response is *package installed*. I turn off my computer, restart my computer, and then try scanlite again. the result is..... [place holder. please wait]

Comment: Try the now installed ScanGear.

Comment: I do not know how to do this. How do I do that? I go to the lower left of my screen where there is a 3 by 3 matrix of dots. I then type Scangear and nothing shows up.

Comment: Maybe there's a reason for ScanGear *not* being offered when we visit the drivers page. There an unnoficial personal repository (PPA) with all the Canon drivers already packaged for Ubuntu: https://launchpad.net/~thierry-f/+archive/ubuntu/fork-michael-gruz .Here as well you can find MF260 listed for the UFRII driver (printer) but NOT for   Scangearmp2 or Cnijfilter2 So maybe scanning not supported in Linux? You may try https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/05/canon-printer-scangear-mp-ubuntu-20-04/ (also for 18.04 and 22.04) just in case (...)

Comment: Please note: 1. you should be running a supported release; 2. following the blog post instructions you may get messages saying already installed, no problem, move to next step; 3. finish with `sudo apt update && sudo full-upgrade`

Comment: If nothing works you may try the other options (via network) but not direct to computer that in your model may work only in Windows or Mac.

Comment: Click on the 3x3 dots on the lower left corner of your desktop. Type "simple" without quotes. Click on the icon for **Simple Scan**. Does it recognize the scanner? If so, put a sheet to scan and click on the **Scan** button in the app.

Comment: Both Simple and XSane definitely work. Now its a matter or checking the details.

Comment: Knowing the Ubuntu version is rather important. Also, give `lsusb -v | grep -A 3 bInterfaceClass.*7`.

Answer (score 2):

While we await knowing the Ubuntu version and for other information, ii might be useful to bring some clarity to the situation as a partial answer.

- The SANE project provides **backends** (drivers) for scanners. Any software that interfaces with a backend is a **frontend**. Examples of frontends are Xsane, simple-scan and skanlite. They need a **working** backend to **exist** to be of any use. In other words, frontends (like the three above) access what a working backend provides and do not bring about scanning by themselves.
- Canon provide scangearmp. The scangearmp package **does not provide** a SANE backend. Therefore, it cannot work with SANE or any of its frontends. A user hoping to use scangearmp with xsane would be disappointed. It fact, scangearmp is a Canon **frontend** that communicates with the scanner directly. Canon can do this because **they** know how the scanner works.
- The Canon MF260 is a **modern** device. The information added to the original report has lsusb showing two 7/1/4 USB interfaces on the device. That means that leveraging [IPP-over-USB](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting#ippoverusb) via an **ipp-usb** Ubuntu package should be possible.
- ipp-usb is provided by default on Ubuntu 22.04 but is only available from the [upstream developer](https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan) on Ubuntu 20.04. Go [here](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04/amd64/) and download and install **ipp-usb** and **sane-airscan**.
- Disconnect and reconnect the device to USB. It would be nice for us to see what is given by `scanimage -L` and `airscan-discover`.
- Now for some comments on what is said and show in **Attempt 9**:

> I do not know which of these options is the right one to choose

The *right one* is the one that works. Does trying any of them produce scanning? I will assume not.

- The entries in the first screenshot are the result of scanner detection over the network. The backend being used is **escl**. This backend is a product of the SANE project. Its not working is an indication of a bug in SANE that is likely fixed in a later version of the backends. These two network entries also appear in the second screenshot.
- The second screenshot has the first two entries using SANE's **pixma** backend. This backend **cannot possibly work** when **ippusnxd** is active. This is irrespective of any bugs in pixma. See the next comment and read [here](https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSDriverlessPrinting#ipp-usb) for why not.
- **escl:http://127.0.0.1:6000** is the interesting entry. The esdl backend is being used again but, this time, using **IPP-over-USB** via **ippusnxd**. ippusbxd has been acknowledged by its author to be highly sub-optimal and has been was removed from the archives after 22.04. It has been replaced by the much more competent **ipp-usb**.
- There isn't any sign of Canon vendor drivers. Even with a correct installation they will not work on a USB connection for the same reason pixma will not work.
- The recommended way forward on 22.04 is, as described above, to **install ipp-usb and sane-airscan**. Giving the requested information would allow the result of this advice to be tested.

Comment: I do not thinjk scangear (I do not know what scangearmp is) works with this particular printer. Though I may be wrong